# asymptotic rate of numbers in an infinite union given the rates in the sets

Tags: general-topology

Suppose to have for every $n\in\mathbb N$ a set of $n$ points
$$
M_n = \{ x_1^{(n)}, \dots, x_n^{(n)}  \}\subseteq \mathbb R^d.
$$ 
Let $E\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ be an open and bounded set such that for  every open ball $B\subseteq E$ we know that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\#\{i | x_i^{(n)}\in B \}}{n} = 0.
$$

Is it true that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\#\{i | x_i^{(n)}\in E \}}{n} = 0?
$$

---

It's obvious that if $E$ is a finite union of balls, then the thesis holds.

Already when $E$ is a countable union of balls $B_j$, the $x_i^{(n)}$ can in a sense escape from every $B_j$ to $B_{j+1}$, so the argument from the finite union fails.

Any idea?

(I'm adding the tag 'distribution theory' since the question comes from a function defined as
$$
\mu(B) := \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\#\{i | x_i^{(n)}\in B \}}{n} 
$$ 
that coincides with a measure for almost all balls, but in general it is not countable additive or subadditive)

Comment: What does $\mu$ have to do with [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. $d=2, E = (0,1)\times(0,1), x_i^{(n)} = (\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$ for each $i,n$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\#\{i : x_i^{(n)} \in E\}}{n} = 1$.

.

There is also a counterexample for $d=1$. Let $B_1,B_2,\dots$ be a countable collection of pairwise positively-separated open intervals in $(0,1)$ (e.g. $B_n = (\frac{1}{2^{2n}},\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}))$, and let $E = \cup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. Let $x_i^{(n)}$ be the center of $B_n$ for each $i,n$. This is clearly a counterexample.

Comment: $E$ must be open

Comment: @Exodd didn't write what I meant. fixed, thanks

Comment: ouch. Yes, you're right, it was simple

Comment: @Exodd a fresh pair of eyes is surprisingly powerful I've learned :)

Comment: @Exodd btw there is also a counter-example for $d=1$. Take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $x_i^{(n)} = n$ for each $i,n$. If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ a ball, then just poke some holes in $E$ to get a counter-example.

Comment: $E$ is bounded by hypothesis, but I guess you can do the same with an infinite union of disjoint open balls that are shrinking